# Jhipster social register and login configuration

Tags: java, spring, angular, jhipster, spring-social

Im trying to implement the register and login with social accounts in my jhipster app. When I created the app I checked the Social Login so jhipster generated everything, it seems the only thing i have to do is register my account in google,facebook to get my public and secret keys. What is the configuration i need to implement it? 
I also followed the instructions in this link: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow#step_1_create_a_client_id_and_client_secret

But I could not figure out how to implement it passing the key generation. Since im using angular 4 and jhipster.

**Social.Component.html**

```
<form ngNoForm action="{{ providerURL }}" method="POST">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-{{ provider }}">
    <i class="fa fa-{{ provider }}"></i>
</button>
<input name="scope" type="hidden" value="{{ providerSetting }}"/>
<input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf }}"/>
```

**Social.Component.ts**

```
export class JhiSocialComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() provider: string;
label: string;
providerSetting: string;
providerURL: string;
csrf: string;

constructor(
    private csrfService: CSRFService,
    private socialService: SocialService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.label = this.provider.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.provider.slice(1);
    this.providerSetting = this.socialService.getProviderSetting(this.provider);
    this.providerURL = this.socialService.getProviderURL(this.provider);
    this.csrf = this.csrfService.getCSRF();
}
```

**Social.Service.ts**
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class SocialService {

constructor() {}

getProviderSetting(provider) {
    switch (provider) {
        case 'google': return 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
        case 'facebook': return 'public_profile,email';
        case 'twitter': return '';
        // jhipster-needle-add-social-button
        default: return 'Provider setting not defined';
    }
}

getProviderURL(provider) {*
    eturn 'signin/' + provider;
}
```

}

**SocialController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/social")
public class SocialController {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialController.class);

private final SocialService socialService;

private final ProviderSignInUtils providerSignInUtils;

public SocialController(SocialService socialService, ProviderSignInUtils providerSignInUtils) {
    this.socialService = socialService;
    this.providerSignInUtils = providerSignInUtils;
}

@GetMapping("/signup")
public RedirectView signUp(WebRequest webRequest, @CookieValue(name = "NG_TRANSLATE_LANG_KEY", required = false, defaultValue = "\"es\"") String langKey) {
    try {
        Connection<?> connection = providerSignInUtils.getConnectionFromSession(webRequest);
        socialService.createSocialUser(connection, langKey.replace("\"", ""));
        return new RedirectView(URIBuilder.fromUri("/#/social-register/" + connection.getKey().getProviderId())
            .queryParam("success", "true")
            .build().toString(), true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception creating social user: ", e);
        return new RedirectView(URIBuilder.fromUri("/#/social-register/no-provider")
            .queryParam("success", "false")
            .build().toString(), true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you set `spring.social.google.appId` and `spring.social.google.appSecret` properties in `application*.yml`?

Comment: Yes i set both of them. @GaëlMarziou